# How do I retrieve a count of timestamps over the first hour of each shift?

Tags: sql-server, join, time, count, min

Okay so this one might be tricky to explain..

What I am trying to do is count the number of loads within the first hour of each shift. What I mean by this is if loading starts at 0630, I want to count the number of times it finished loading from 0630 to 0700. If loading started at 0705, the count would be from 0705 to 0800 etc.

Here's what I have to work with thus far:

```
SELECT est.shift_date
    ,CASE est.shift_ident
        WHEN '1' THEN 'D'
        WHEN '2'THEN 'N'
        END AS shift_ident
    ,min(est.start_timestamp) AS start
FROM equip_status_trans est
JOIN equip_status_code esc ON esc.status_code est.status_code
WHERE est.shift_date >= (getdate() - 180)
    AND esc.status_desc 'LU Loading'
    AND est.equip_ident IN (
        'S803'
        ,'S804'
        )
GROUP BY est.shift_date
    ,est.shift_ident
    ,est.equip_ident
```

Ignoring the filters, what this gets me is the date, shift identity, and start timestamp of loading for each shift.

I also have

```
SELECT est.shift_date
    ,CASE est.shift_ident
        WHEN '1' THEN 'D'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'N'
        END AS shift_ident
    ,count(est.end_timestamp) AS count
    ,min(est.start_timestamp) AS start
FROM equip_status_trans est
JOIN equip_status_code esc ON esc.status_code = est.status_code
WHERE est.shift_date >= (getdate() - 180)
    AND esc.status_desc = 'LU Loading'
    AND est.equip_ident IN (
        'S803'
        ,'S804'
        )
GROUP BY est.shift_date
    ,est.shift_ident
    ,est.equip_ident
    ,datepart(hh, est.end_timestamp)
```

which gives me the date, shift identity, start timestamp of loading, and the load count for each hour. The start timestamps are the minimum loading timestamps for each hour instead of the minimum timestamp for each shift.

The problem I'm having is that every time I try and join the two, it returns the load count for every hour during the shift instead of just the first hour.

As someone very new to SQL Server, what is the easiest way to go about this?

Much appreciated

---

Here's what the join statement looks like

```
 SELECT est.shift_date, 
    CASE est.shift_ident 
        WHEN '1' THEN 'D' 
        WHEN '2' THEN 'N' 
        END as shift_ident, 
    min(est.start_timestamp) as start
    , est.equip_ident, d1.count
FROM  equip_status_trans est 
join equip_status_code esc on esc.status_code = est.status_code 
left outer join
    (SELECT est2.shift_date, 
        CASE est2.shift_ident 
            WHEN '1' THEN 'D' WHEN '2' THEN 'N' 
            END as shift_ident
        , count(est2.end_timestamp) as count
        , min(est2.start_timestamp) as start
        , est2.equip_ident
    FROM equip_status_trans est2 
    join equip_status_code esc2 on esc2.status_code = est2.status_code
    WHERE est2.shift_date >= (getdate() - 180) 
        and esc2.status_desc = 'LU Loading' 
        and est2.equip_ident IN('S803', 'S804')
    GROUP BY est2.shift_date
        , est2.shift_ident
        , est2.equip_ident
        , datepart(hh, est2.end_timestamp)
    )d1 on est.start_timestamp = d1.start
WHERE est.shift_date >= (getdate() - 180) 
and esc.status_desc = 'LU Loading' 
and est.equip_ident IN('S803', 'S804')
GROUP BY est.shift_date, est.shift_ident, est.equip_ident, d1.count
```

Comment: what does the join code look like?

Comment: Just added it to the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of pseudo-SQL that abstracts-away some of your select data that is not pertinent to the join and filters, but I believe you'll want something like this:

```
WITH START_TIME_PER_SHIFT AS
(/*select statement that gives you the minimum start per shift */)

SELECT EST.SHIFT_DATE,
       COUNT(EST.END_TIMESTAMP) AS COUNT,
       ST_TIME.START AS START
  FROM EQUIP_STATUS_TRANS EST
  JOIN START_TIME_PER_SHIFT ST_TIME
    ON EST.SHIFT_DATE = ST_TIME.SHIFT_DATE
   AND DATEPART(hh, EST.END_TIMESTAMP) =
       DATEPART(hh, EST.SHIFT_DATE) --get the next hour from the shift start; only join records that are within that first hour
 GROUP BY EST.SHIFT_DATE ST_TIME.START
```

Perhaps this...

```
WITH START_TIME_PER_SHIFT AS
 (SELECT est.shift_date,
         CASE est.shift_ident
           WHEN '1' THEN
            'D'
           WHEN '2' THEN
            'N'
         END AS shift_ident,
         /*est.equip_ident, (did you need this grouping as well?)*/
         min(est.start_timestamp) AS start
    FROM equip_status_trans est
    JOIN equip_status_code esc
      ON esc.status_code est.status_code
   WHERE est.shift_date >= (getdate() - 180)
     AND esc.status_desc 'LU Loading'
     AND est.equip_ident IN ('S803', 'S804')
   GROUP BY est.shift_date, est.shift_ident
  /*,est.equip_ident*/
  )

SELECT est.shift_date,
       CASE est.shift_ident
         WHEN '1' THEN
          'D'
         WHEN '2' THEN
          'N'
       END AS shift_ident,
       /*est.equip_ident, (did you need this grouping as well?) */
       count(est.end_timestamp) AS count,
       st_time.start AS start
  FROM equip_status_trans est
  JOIN START_TIME_PER_SHIFT st_time
    ON est.shift_date = st_time.shift_date
   AND CASE est.shift_ident WHEN '1' THEN 'D' WHEN '2' THEN 'N' END = st_time.shift_ident
 /*AND est.equip_ident = st_time.equip_ident*/
  JOIN equip_status_code esc
    ON esc.status_code = est.status_code
 WHERE est.shift_date >= (getdate() - 180)
   AND datepart(hh, est.shift_date) = datepart(hh, est.end_timestamp)
   AND esc.status_desc = 'LU Loading'
   AND est.equip_ident IN ('S803', 'S804')
 GROUP BY est.shift_date, est.shift_ident, /*est.equip_ident,*/ st_time.start
```

Comment: Your example is great except it only includes N's for shift_ident - I can't seem to figure out why.. Any ideas?

Comment: I found out what was wrong in the above comment. Now it works great!